# git merge branch does not give conflicts

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

I have a git repository that has one file called hi.txt. It has only one branch i.e. master. Its content is `Hi this is it.` I committed this change and then checked out it in a new branch called `newb` using `git checkout -b newb`. Now in this branch i changed the text to `Hi this is not it.` I committed this code too. Now i switched to master using `git checkout master` and then merged the `newb` branch using git merge `newb`. Now git should give me a conflict because both branches have different versions of the same file but it does not. It overwrites the content of `master`branch with `newb` branch so content of `hi.txt` becomes `Hi this is not it.` Is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Turns out what i was looking for was `git rebase newb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shall there be a conflict?

- you created `hi.txt` in `master`
- you created a new branch `newb` and modified `hi.txt`
- you switch back to `master` and the changes done in `newb` are merged into `master`

**That's the way it should work.** We're not using SVN, eh?

Things could be different if you changed `hi.txt` in `master` **after** creating `newb`: this would lead to a state where there are modifications on both branches.

But your workflow described above shall not lead to any problems.

Have a deeper read about branching and merging in the Git Book:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

---

**Edit:**  According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144246/git-merge-branch-does-not-give-conflicts/22144537#comment33602064_22144537), you only want to know which files are different between `master` and `newb`. This can easily be achieved using

```
git diff --name-only master newb
```

Comment: But it wanted git to tell me the same file had been modified in the other branch. How can i do that?

Comment: @lovesh: put answer to your comment into my answer.